# C++ Array of templated objects: Is it UB to cast to a common non-type template parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, casting, containers, undefined-behavior

### Background

I'm trying to modernize a C-style API that "registers" to a container (an array) TU-static variables from across an embedded application to group them into functionally-related groups and to track these groups' values throughout the application lifetime. This interface supports multiple variable types by means of a tagged void pointer, which needs conditional logic to cast back to a properly typed value when needed (e.g. for logging).

Compiler: `ARM GCC 8.2`

Full code: [Compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/vNSpSV)

### Stable Code

Here's an example embodiment of a variable "wrapper" and a collection of these wrappers:

```cpp
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstring>
#include <array>

enum class VarT {
    kUndefined,
    kBoolean,
    kUinteger
};

/* "Wraps" the desired variable-to-register */
struct Var {
    const VarT val_t;
    const void * const val;
    const char * const name; /* User-facing var name */

    constexpr Var(const char * const name, void* value, VarT type)
        : val_t{type}
        , val{value}
        , name{name}
    { }
};

/* A naive attempt at generalizing the templated Group objects */
struct Base { };

/* A group of `Var`s */
template<std::size_t TNumVars>
struct VarGroup : Base {
    /* Placed first strategically -- shared data */
    std::size_t num_vars = TNumVars;
    /* Because this is "flexible" from VarGroup to VarGroup
     * due to TNumVars template parameter */
    std::array<Var, TNumVars> vars;  

    explicit constexpr VarGroup(std::array<Var, TNumVars> var_arr)
        : vars{var_arr}
    { }
};
```

### Questionable Code

An attempt at making a collection of VarGroups:

```cpp
/* What makes up the collection of VarGroups */
struct GroupHandle {
    /* User-facing VarGroup name */
    const char * name;   
    /* Pointer to statically allocated VarGroup in other TUs */
    const Base * group;  
};

const std::size_t max_groups = 5;

/* The array of VarGroups */
auto groups = std::array<GroupHandle, max_groups>{};
std::size_t groups_idx = 0;

void regGroup(const char * name, const Base * g) {
    /* Ignore bounds checking for the example */
    groups[groups_idx++] = GroupHandle{name, g};
}

/*   THE QUESTIONABLE CAST   */
/*             |             */
/*             v             */
const VarGroup<1>* getGroup(const char * name) {
    for (auto& g : groups) {
        if (std::strcmp(name, g.name) == 0) {
            return static_cast<const VarGroup<1>*>(g.group);
        }
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

### Test Code

```cpp
/* Some variables to track */
std::uint32_t uint_var = 42;
bool bool_var = true;

/* Create a group */
constexpr auto group1 = []() {
    std::array vars = {
        Var("g1 uint var", &uint_var, VarT::kUinteger),
        Var("g1 bool var", &bool_var, VarT::kBoolean)
    };
    return VarGroup(vars);
}();

/* Create another group */
constexpr auto group2 = []() {
    std::array vars = {
        Var("g2 uint var", &uint_var, VarT::kUinteger)
    };
    return VarGroup(vars);
}();

/* test */
int main() {
    regGroup("group one", &group1);
    regGroup("group two", &group2);

    /* get group one and iterate over all of its vars */
    auto g1 = getGroup("group one");
    if (g1 != nullptr) {
        printf("Group one vars: \n");
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < g1->num_vars; i++) {
            auto var = g1->vars[i];
            printf("%s | %d | %d\n", var.name, var.val_t, *((int*)var.val));
        }
    }

    uint_var = 7;

    /* get group two and iterate over all of its vars */
    auto g2 = getGroup("group two");
    if (g2 != nullptr) {
        printf("Group two vars: \n");
        for (std::size_t i = 0; i < g2->num_vars; i++) {
            auto var = g2->vars[i];
            printf("%s | %d | %d\n", var.name, var.val_t, *((int*)var.val));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Group one vars:
g1 uint var | 2 | 42
g1 bool var | 1 | 1
Group two vars:
g2 uint var | 2 | 7
```

This works as desired, but certainly feels dirty. Does this instance of type coercion -- though seemingly inconsequential as nothing but static array size allocation depends on the non-type template argument -- result in unsafe

Comment: Could you compress it to a smaller example

Comment: Can't you use `std::vector` instead of `std::array` inside `VarGroup` (and so drop template), then you would have the same type and would be able to have `std::vector<VarGroup>`.

Comment: If your classes have nothing in common, they should not have a common base class. If they do have something in common, that something should be in their common base class. An empty base class is basically a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically you are casting `VarGroup<2>*` to `VarGroup<1>*` but these are different classes.

The `VarGroup<x>` is not standard layout so you expecting common initial sequence to work (`num_vars`) is not valid. You can perhaps put that `num_vars` into `Base` for it to be available in legal manner. Your access of `g2->vars` through pointer of wrong type is totally illegal since `VarGroup<1>::vars` and `VarGroup<2>::vars` are of different type.

Bottom line is that your code contains "undefined behavior", it may appear to work
today but stop tomorrow or after slight change in code or compiler options.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

```
struct Var {
    const std::variant<std::uint32_t*, bool*> val;
    const char* name; /* User-facing var name */

    constexpr Var(const char* const name, std::variant<std::uint32_t*, bool*> value)
        : val{value}
        , name{name}
    { }
};

struct VarGroup
{
    std::vector<Var> vars;  

    explicit VarGroup(std::vector<Var> var_arr)
        : vars{std::move(var_arr)}
    {}
};

using GroupHandle = std::map<std::string, VarGroup>;
```

And then test code would be

```
/* Some variables to track */
std::uint32_t uint_var = 42;
bool bool_var = true;

/* Create a group */
constexpr auto group1 = []() {
    std::vector vars = {
        Var("g1 uint var", &uint_var),
        Var("g1 bool var", &bool_var)
    };
    return VarGroup(std::move(vars));
};

/* Create another group */
constexpr auto group2 = []() {
    std::vector vars = {
        Var("g2 uint var", &uint_var)
    };
    return VarGroup(vars);
};

/* test */
int main() {
    GroupHandle groups{
        {"group one", group1()},
        {"group two", group2()}
};

    /* get group one and iterate over all of its vars */
    if (auto it = groups.find("group one"); it != groups.end()) {
        std::cout << "Group one vars: \n";
        for (const auto& var : (*it).second.vars) {

            std::cout << var.name << " | ";
            std::visit([](const auto* p){ std::cout << *p << std::endl; }, var.val);
        }
    }

    uint_var = 7;

    /* get group two and iterate over all of its vars */
    if (auto it = groups.find("group two"); it != groups.end()) {
        std::cout << "Group two vars: \n";
        for (const auto& var : (*it).second.vars) {

            std::cout << var.name << " | ";
            std::visit([](const auto* p){ std::cout << *p << std::endl; }, var.val);
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0191319ef4eb7246)

If you really want to avoid dynamic allocation with `std::vector`(`std::map`), you might use instead `std::span` and keep viewed data alive (static constexpr array).

Comment: While this is an elegant full-on STL solution, unfortunately it yields a ~10x larger binary than the code under question, particularly given that this is for an embedded firmware application. I have solved my design by turning `GroupHandle` into more of a `string_view`-like entity, which exposes a simple iterator interface to the `Var` array inside of a given `VarGroup` and sidesteps the need for a handle to the various `VarGroup<N>` instances.